# Javascript Function's Output is Rails Function's Input - Dependency

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dependencies

I want to find content for a related tag in my table. But tags are returned by javascript function, therefore when I try to evaluate Find(tag_id) since rails first evaluates its code prior to the javascript code, my function's input become `{%= file.tag  %}`

Following code is a part of my table:

```
<td class="title"><span>Tag:  <%= Tag.find("{%= file.tag  %}")%></span></td>
```

and I get the following error:

> Couldn't find Tag with id={%= file.tag  %}

How can I solve this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

Rails runs *before* JavaScript as Rails is running on the Server and once done it's sent to the client where the JavaScript is executed.

You'll have to re-architect this to either do the Tag search completely on the server, or your JavaScript has to call back the server to find the tag through an AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you very much firstly. So you mean I can call Tag.find() method with AJAX ?

Comment: You would have to write a controller action in Rails that does the lookup and processing of `Tag.find` you want on the server. Then you can call that from the client using a AJAX call and use the result to manipulate the Page.